# mysql db: field will only accept json like string

Tags: mysql, json

I am working with a table that has a string column. When I look up the existing values I can see that the values are a json like string but surrounded by double quotes "" and with escaped quotes.

Now I try to update one of the field values with the below query but the query only accepts json like strings not surrounded by double quotes also it will give me "Error Code 3140: Invalid JSON text".

When I look at the updated values I can see that my newly set field and the previously existing field are formatted differently. When I retrieve the values in my script I get an "Internal Server Error"...

Unfortunately I can't share the whole script but I would like to ask if anybody has any ideas on how to make sure my newly entered JSON like string behaves the same way as previously existing strings.

Here is the query I am using to set the Field Value:

```
UPDATE case_inputs 
SET data = '{ "inv_start_time": "2022-02-01 00:00:00", ...}'
WHERE case_id = 45 AND data_type = 1;
```

And here is a screenshot of how the table looks afterward:

It can be seen that the string for case_id 40 (previously existing) and for case_id 45 (new, modified by the above query) look quite differently. The one for case_id 45 causes my script to crash so I would like it to look the same as the one in case_id 40 but am unsure of how to achieve this.

[image]

Edit: Note that the data type of the column appears to be JSON as I figured out using "DESCRIBE" but I still don't know why the previous entry appears different from my newly created entry.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share show create table for this column ? How do you know that column type is not json ?

Comment: Provide a sample according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @TyagiAkhilesh sorry for being a noob, I didn't create this table... how can I figure out that the column type is JSON? And if it is JSON how come the existing entry looks so different from my new entry...

EDIT: after googling some more I found out that the column type is indeed JSON using DESCRIBE

Comment: Then you have your answer. DB shall reject any input that is not confirming to JSON structure.